# How to make two attributes in XML to be unique (DTD)

Tags: xml, dtd

How can I make two attributes in XML to be unique, for example in SQL I can do this by this code:

```
create table tablename(
  StudentID varchar(20),
  SubjectID varchar(20),
  UNIQUE(StudentID,SubjectID)
)
```

On the other hand, I have the following code in XML:

```
<root>
  <student StudentID="s1" />
  <subject SubjectID="sb1" />
  <tablename StudentID="s1" SubjectID="sb1" />
</root>
```

How can I make that the attributes `StudentID` and `SubjectID` both become UNIQUE?

Comment: Please include your code in a `code` section and not as picture with an edit.

Comment: Next time please care more about the code formatting ;-)

Comment: What do you mean by "become unique"? They're already unique as far as the values go. You can declare those attributes as type ID in the DTD to enforce uniqueness. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: Ok so i dont want DTD to allow me write this two times <tablename StudentID="s1" SubjectID="sb1">

Comment: How are the `StudentID`/`SubjectID` attributes in `tablename` relate to the same named attributes in `student` and `subject`? Does one reference the other? Are they unrelated?

Comment: StudentID is ID in element Student , SubjectID is ID in element Subject, and StudentID,SubjectID are IDREF in tablename how can i make that the same value doesnt apper twice in these attributes

Answer (score 0):

```
<!ATTLIST student StudentID ID #REQUIRED>
<!ATTLIST subject SubjectID ID #REQUIRED>
<!ATTLIST tablename StudentID IDREF #REQUIRED
                    SubjectID IDREF #REQUIRED>
```

From your comment ("`StudentID` is ID in element `Student`, `SubjectID` is ID in element `Subject`, and `StudentID`, `SubjectID` are IDREF in `tablename`.  How can i make sure that the same value doesn't appear twice in these attributes?") it sounds as if this is what you already have in the DTD.

In other words: you have *already* ensured that the same value does not appear twice in the `student/StudentID` and `subject/SubjectID` attributes.  No value can appear more than once in a document as the value of an attribute declared as ID.

If what you mean is "How do I ensure that no two `tablename` elements have the same `StudentID`, `SubjectID` pair?", the answer is:  with application code.  There is no good way to do it with the DTD.